# node.js cookie with request.jar

Tags: node.js, authentication, cookies, jar, request

Im scraping a site, that requires authentication. I'm using node.js and request with a jar to store the cookie.

My problem:
I got two routes /login and /api, when i login to the website i store the cookie in the login route/file how can i then use the same cookie in /api?

```
        login.js:

        var request = require('request');
        var jar = request.jar();

        var payload = querystring.stringify({
            username: username,
            password: password,
            request_token: token,
        });

        var options = {
            ..
            ..
            method: 'POST',
            body: payload,
            jar: jar <---------- Valid cookie
        };

       request(options, function (error, response, body) {
            // Code here
        });


       --------------------------------

        api.js:

        var request = require('request');
        var jar = request.jar();

           var options = {
            method: "get",
            url: baseUrl,
            jar: jar <-------- Not sat anymore
        };


        request(options, function (error, response, body) {

            if (error) {
                res.send(error);
                return;
            }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create a new module and centralize the approach. Here I created the module `jar.js`, that has exported functions that allow seting/getting the jar.

You orginal code just needs to now acount for this new way. In each file I added the line `var jar = require('./jar');`

```
jar.js:

var request = require('request');
var jar;

module.exports = function getJar() {
   if(jar)
     return jar;
   else {
     jar = request.jar();
     return jar;
  }
}

module.exports = function setJar(jarParam) {
  jar = jarParam;
}

 --------------------------------
  login.js:

    var jar = require('./jar');
    var request = require('request');
    jar.setJar(request.jar());

    var payload = querystring.stringify({
        username: username,
        password: password,
        request_token: token,
    });

    var options = {
        ..
        ..
        method: 'POST',
        body: payload,
        jar: jar.getJar() <---------- Valid cookie, from jar module
    };

   request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        // Code here
    });


  --------------------------------

    api.js:

    var request = require('request');
    var jar = require('./jar');

       var options = {
        method: "get",
        url: baseUrl,
        jar: jar.getJar() <---------- Valid cookie, from jar module
    };
```